# Can we convert entity to dto/pojo object patially?

Tags: java, entity, getter-setter, pojo

Is there any approach to convert entity to dto object partially? Or are there any best practices for using the entity, pojo/dto and response object in MVC pattern?

Comment: this is completely based on your requirement, so this is something you'll have to implement yourself

Comment: If you serialize it to JSON via Jackson you could have a look at its annotations, like `@JsonView` and `@JsonIgnore`. (There are a lot more)

Answer (score 0):

You have couple of approaches. I assume you have a web project.

1. **Manual mapping approach.** Create Dto map it manually to your entity. This would involve all the boilerplate code around it - Builders, all argument Constructor, getters, setters whatever approach you will use to populate the DTO.
   The different hydration Technics apply in different situations.  Builder pattern presumes you would have an immutable objects. Getters and Setters are supported out opf the box by frameworks as Jackson. You may decide to minimize your boilerplate code by using lombok, imutables or other frameworks.
2. **Mapping framework**. Another option would be to use a supplied mapper like ObjectMapper, or FastMap there may be other choices. This would remove large portion of manual mapping you would need to establish following aproach 1.
3. **Deserializer**. Example of such aproach would be **spring-data-rest** where your repository returns the entities straight which are than serialized in JSON . Using normal spring MVC this would be to return your entity straight to your controller layer and based on annotations or other means (serializers) map it to your network format JSON, XML whatever you use.

These are the different options. Which one is best depends on your usecase.

Comment: Currently using ModelMapper for converting the whole object but it does not provide the partial conversion. Also comparing apache BeanUtils etc.

Comment: @arpit_writes you can skip properties with ModelMapper. Use this functionality.

Comment: you can also use provider to give a subset of properties to be mapped.

Answer (score 0):

One of possible approaches is copy constructor. The example below.

```
// entity annotations ...
public class EntityExample {

    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private Integer score;

    // getters and setters ...
}


public class DtoExample {
    private Long id;
    pricate String name;

    // For serialization and deserialization
    public DtoExample() {

    }

    public DtoExample(EntityExample entity) {
        this.id = entity.getId();
        this.name = entity.getName();
    }

    // getters and setters ...
}
```